# Laravel Elixir Browserify Unexpected Token Error

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs, laravel-elixir

I'm currently working on a project involving Laravel, React, React-Router and React-Refetch. However, I'm having some problems with Browserify it seems. Here is my gulpfile:

Gulpfile

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-livereload');

elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;


elixir(function(mix) {
mix.browserify('app.js', 'public/js/all.js', null, {transform: 'babelify'})
.sass('app.scss')
  .livereload();

});
```

When running gulp watch, I get the following error: **gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Browserify Failed!: Unexpected token (9:2) while parsing file:**

The abve file that throws the error is just the basic PromiseStateContainer from  [github](https://gist.github.com/ryanbrainard/788c12c3811d3da13124#file-promisestatecontainer-jsx)

I've read that the new version of babel does not include es2015 presets, however in on the Elixir repo it seems to say that Elixir has included them by default, thus I'm not sure what the problem could be.